# Claim edit done while logged out

Tags: discussion, editing

I edited this answer: https://superuser.com/a/435420/135459 but didn't realize I was logged out. Can / should I do anything to mark that edit as mine? Since it was entered as an unregistered user, it's under review at the moment.

Comment: Just wait for it to be approved (or rejected)

Comment: I realized after a moment that it would have been under review anyway because I only have 124 rep on this site right now. My actual concern, though, isn't about it getting reviewed, but rather being blamed/credited for the edit.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it for just one edit :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply. I'll let it go.

Comment: Don't worry about getting credit for the edit wasn't approved.

Comment: Are the contents of that declined edit available to those with more reputation or to a moderator?

Comment: Unless you have a link to the edit proposal in the queue, no, there isn't.  Does it matter though?

Comment: I think it was a good edit, turning a link-only answer into a real answer and I'd like to ask another meta question "Why was my edit declined?", but having the original text would be helpful in writing such a question.

Comment: @TecBrat Mods can certainly see the declined edit. Here is a link. https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/677760

Comment: Given the OP hasn't been around for 5 years and the edit appears to reasonably fix a link only answer I have approved the edit.

Comment: @TecBrat I can tell you the reason it was declined multiple people thought you were changing what the author of the answer said.

Comment: It might have helped if you had made it clear that the text you were adding to the answer came from the link that was already in the answer. But I suspect that some people are biased against anonymous edits, and hold them to a higher level of scrutiny.